# Errors with xmlparserv2.jar and Oracle Database

Tags: java, xml, oracle, hibernate

When I run my code against an oracle database, I get the following error:

```
Error parsing XML (31) : http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd<Line 31, Column 2>: XML-20068: (Fatal Error) content model is not deterministic
[07 Aug 2012 14:41:36,643](UTC 20:41:36) WARN   ApplicationLifecycle      | Unable to install module at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Unable to read XML
at org.hibernate.util.xml.MappingReader.readMappingDocument(MappingReader.java:101)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.add(Configuration.java:513)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.add(Configuration.java:509)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.add(Configuration.java:716)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:801)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:2344)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:2310)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2290)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2243)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2158)
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: Error on line 31 of document http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd : http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd<Line 31, Column 2>: XML-20068: (Fatal Error) content model is not deterministic Nested exception: http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd<Line 31, Column 2>: XML-20068: (Fatal Error) content model is not deterministic
at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:482)
at org.hibernate.util.xml.MappingReader.readMappingDocument(MappingReader.java:75)
... 20 more
```

The main error is `Error parsing XML (31) : http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd<Line 31, Column 2>: XML-20068: (Fatal Error) content model is not deterministic`

When I then delete the jar `xmlparserv2.jar` I then get the following error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/xml/parser/v2/XMLParseException
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleSQLXML.setString(OracleSQLXML.java:415)
at com.capitaliq.loader.persistence.messaging.QueueUtils$1FlushMessages.execute(QueueUtils.java:358)
at com.capitaliq.loader.persistence.messaging.QueueUtils.flushMessages(QueueUtils.java:378)
at com.capitaliq.loader.persistence.AbstractControlFacadeHelper$ControlFacadeRetrier.performOperation(AbstractControlFacadeHelper.java:303)
at com.capitaliq.loader.persistence.AbstractRetryLimitedDurationWithTimout.retryContinuously(AbstractRetryLimitedDurationWithTimout.java:66)
at com.capitaliq.loader.persistence.AbstractControlFacadeHelper.performRetries(AbstractControlFacadeHelper.java:138)
... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLParseException
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
... 18 more
at com.capitaliq.loader.control.ClientManager$HeartbeatCity.safeRun(ClientManager.java:429)
at com.capitaliq.common.thread.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:57)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/xml/parser/v2/XMLParseException
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleSQLXML.setString(OracleSQLXML.java:415)
... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLParseException
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
... 18 more  
   Caused by: oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLParseException
```

From the stack traces, i can deduce I need to have this jar in my class path to read xml, but I can't have it because it is not compatible with my version of hibernate. I did not have this error until I upgraded to Hibernate 3.6. **My question is, has anyone had this before? And is there another xmlparser that works with the oracle database?**

If I run my code against a SQL database I get the same error if the jar is on the class path. But if I delete everything works. So I know it has to do with the oracle database. Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
unjar the file using the following command:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin\jar" -xvf xmlparserv2.jar
```

Change the entries in the files in the META-INF/services as follows:

- **for** `javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory`   **replace** `oracle.xml.jaxp.JXDocumentBuilderFactory`  **with** `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl`
- **for** javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory **replace** oracle.xml.jaxp.JXSAXParserFactory **with** com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl
- **for** javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory **replace** oracle.xml.jaxp.JXSAXTransformerFactory **with** com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl

Re jar the file using the following command:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin\jar" -cvfm xmlparserv2.jar META-INF\MANIFEST.MF -c ./ .
```

copy this new xmlparserv2.jar file into the lib directory of your project

Comment: You shouldn't need to unpack the JAR to change the parser factories used.  Each of those factories can be set via a System property or by placing a property file in the JRE. See the documentation of DocumentBuilderFactory#newInstance() for instance.

Comment: Some times we can't access or modify the JRE or start up.  Here's a note with a similar approach we followed.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29078498/classpath-issue-with-xmlparserv2-jar-in-was-8-5-5/36601673#36601673

Comment: My xmlparserv2.jar wasn't in jdk bin, found in \.m2\repository\com\oracle\jdbc\ . I used maven.