# Classpath Issue with xmlparserV2.jar in WAS 8.5.5

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, websphere

I had a severe issue in WAS 8.5.5. I have included the **xmlparserV2.jar** in JVM classpath as per my requirement. I have restarted the WAS and server start to failed with the follow errors. I have removed the jar and tested. Server is working fine with out that entry.

Please let me know the reason and how can i resolve it.

```
[3/16/15 6:30:12:406 PDT] 00000001 MBeanDescript W   ADMN0001W: The service is unable to parse the MBean descriptor file com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.DescriptorParseException: ADMN0001W: The service is unable to parse the MBean descriptor file com/ibm/ws/management/descriptor/xml/AdminService.xml.
at com.ibm.ws.management.descriptor.MBeanDescriptorLoader.loadDescriptor(MBeanDescriptorLoader.java:182)
at com.ibm.ws.management.descriptor.MBeanDescriptorManager.loadDescriptorFile(MBeanDescriptorManager.java:415)
at com.ibm.ws.management.descriptor.MBeanDescriptorManager.getDescriptor(MBeanDescriptorManager.java:190)
at com.ibm.ws.management.MBeanFactoryImpl.activateMBean(MBeanFactoryImpl.java:507)

[3/16/15 6:30:12:500 PDT] 00000001 FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\logs\ffdc\server1_b9ae2bfa_15.03.16_06.30.12.4211342510407965994963.txt com.ibm.ws.management.component.AdminImpl.initialize 217
[3/16/15 6:30:12:500 PDT] 00000001 AdminInitiali A   ADMN0015I: The administration service is initialized.
[3/16/15 6:30:12:562 PDT] 00000001 MBeanDescript W   ADMN0001W: The service is unable to parse the MBean descriptor file com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.DescriptorParseException: ADMN0001W: The service is unable to parse the MBean descriptor file com/ibm/ws/management/descriptor/xml/ConfigRepository.xml.
at com.ibm.ws.management.descriptor.MBeanDescriptorLoader.loadDescriptor(MBeanDescriptorLoader.java:182)
at com.ibm.ws.management.descriptor.MBeanDescriptorManager.loadDescriptorFile(MBeanDescriptorManager.java:415)
at com.ibm.ws.management.descriptor.MBeanDescriptorManager.getDescriptor(MBeanDescriptorManager.java:190)
at com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\logs\ffdc\server1_b9ae2bfa_15.03.16_06.30.12.5627002919638891875819.txt com.ibm.ws.management.repository.FileRepository.initialize 149

[3/16/15 6:30:12:578 PDT] 00000001 FileRepositor E   ADMR0006E: An error occurred activating MBean: com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.AdminException: ADMN0005E: The service is unable to activate MBean: type ConfigRepository, collaborator com.ibm.ws.management.repository.FileRepository@df91d010, configuration ID repository, descriptor null.
at com.ibm.ws.management.MBeanFactoryImpl.activateMBean(MBeanFactoryImpl.java:772)
at com.ibm.ws.management.MBeanFactoryImpl.activateMBean(MBeanFactoryImpl.java:476)
```

Answer (score 2):

The JAR file includes a META-INF\services directory which includes files that will override the XML processors being used by your server.

From Java SE javadoc

> Use the Services API (as detailed in the JAR specification), if available, to determine the classname. The Services API will look for a classname in the file META-INF/services/javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory in jars available to the runtime.

I used 7-zip to delete the files from the META-INF\services and used that JAR instead.  My XML Object parsing works now and everything else is un-effected.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Is this issue got resolved?

Becuase I am aslo facing same kind of issue.
First getting - **java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLParseException** to resolve this issue if  we add xmlparserv2.jar in JDBC class path then application running fine but my JVM got crush (not bale to login cosole). Server is behaving properly after removing this jar from classpath.