# Conflict when adding XMLParserV2 jar on Javax.xml.ws service

Tags: java, xml, web-services, xml-parsing

When I add jar `XMlparverv2` in my project, I get the below exceptions:

```
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Unable to create envelope from given source: 
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.interceptors.MessageModeOutInterceptor$MessageModeOutInterceptorInternal.handleMessage(MessageModeOutInterceptor.java:243)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.interceptors.MessageModeOutInterceptor$MessageModeOutInterceptorInternal.handleMessage(MessageModeOutInterceptor.java:182)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:255)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:544)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:341)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:294)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invokeWrapped(ClientImpl.java:329)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.DispatchImpl.invoke(DispatchImpl.java:346)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.DispatchImpl.invoke(DispatchImpl.java:220)
    at com.test.comp.CallWebservice.DispatchService(CallWebservice.java:64)
    at com.test.comp.CallWebservice.main(CallWebservice.java:135)
Caused by: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Unable to create envelope from given source: 
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.EnvelopeFactory.createEnvelope(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPPart1_1Impl.createEnvelopeFromSource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPPartImpl.getEnvelope(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.getSOAPBody(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.interceptors.MessageModeOutInterceptor$MessageModeOutInterceptorInternal.handleMessage(MessageModeOutInterceptor.java:227)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: XML-22103: (Fatal Error) DOMResult can not be this kind of node.
    at oracle.xml.jaxp.JXTransformer.reportException(JXTransformer.java:812)
    at oracle.xml.jaxp.JXTransformer.transform(JXTransformer.java:298)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.util.transform.EfficientStreamingTransformer.transform(Unknown Source)
    ... 15 more
```

But without `XMLparserV2` jar, my code runs without any problems. I suspect there is a conflict between the two parsers. I also need `XMLParserv2` for converting oracle `XMLtype` to string.

Could you please someone help to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The JAR file includes a META-INF\services directory which includes files that will override the XML processors being used by your server.

From Java SE javadoc

> Use the Services API (as detailed in the JAR specification), if available, to determine the classname. The Services API will look for a classname in the file META-INF/services/javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory in jars available to the runtime.

I used 7-zip to delete the files from the META-INF\services and used that JAR instead.  My XML Object parsing works now and everything else is un-effected.

[image]

Comment: Please don't post link only answers to other Stack Overflow answers. Instead, vote/flag to close as duplicate, or, if the question is not a duplicate, *tailor the answer to this specific question.*

Comment: Is this better now ?  Not sure on correct process / criteria  to mark as duplicate etc

Comment: See [How should duplicate questions be handled?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled)

Comment: @Zizouz212 The above comments questions grbonk's answer being copy+pasted into multiple locations.

Comment: @CubeJockey Ah, didn't see that, so I was confused. Thought they were telling the user to mark the question as dupe :/

Comment: Initially I just linked my answer from another question that might be duplicate.   See:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29078498/classpath-issue-with-xmlparserv2-jar-in-was-8-5-5/36601673#36601673                          I was downvoted for cross linking so I put my answer from there to here.  I wasn't 100% if it was duplicate and un-comfortable marking it as such.  I opted just to leave both open and let someone with more experience mark as duplicate if appropriate.